# How to configure VPN to work with an API on ubuntu server

Tags: vpn, openvpn, linux-networking

I have deployed a Nodejs API on the Ubuntu server and I am using NordVPN on the server but after enabling the VPN I am not able to connect to my API from browser and also SSH for remote access is not working.

**When i try to ssh**:

C:\Users\mvsrs>ssh root@159.65.136.202

ssh: connect to host 159.65.136.202 port 22: Connection timed out

**I tried these commands on server terminal**:

ip route add 122.XXX.XXX.XXX via 159.65.136.202 dev eth0

122.xxx.xxx.xxx => my pc public IP
159.65.136.202 => is my droplet IPv4

Comment: Mostly, commercial VPN providers force all traffic on a system through the tunnel.You have some options, a couple are - use Nords's port forwarding, - change your VPN config to not pull routes and set up your own.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, please descripe more exactly what is what, if you want to ssh to 159'th and 122 is your router, then the command is wrongly used, so on the first you show a windows command on the second a linux - what are you really trying?!